# Why am I seeing different results for these two nearly identical Ruby regex patterns, and why is one matching what I think it shouldn't?

Tags: ruby, regex, unicode, character-class

Using Ruby 1.9.2, I have the following Ruby code in IRB:

```
> r1 = /^(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[\W]).{8,20}$/i
> r2 = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W).{8,20}$/i
> a = ["password", "1password", "password1", "pass1word", "password 1"]
> a.each {|p| puts "r1: #{r1.match(p) ? "+" : "-"} \"#{p}\"".ljust(25) + "r2: #{r2.match(p) ? "+" : "-"} \"#{p}\""}
```

This results in the following output:

```
r1: - "password"         r2: - "password"
r1: + "1password"        r2: - "1password"
r1: + "password1"        r2: - "password1"
r1: + "pass1word"        r2: - "pass1word"
r1: + "password 1"       r2: + "password 1"
```

1.) Why do the results differ?

2.) Why would `r1` match on strings 2, 3 and 4? Wouldn't the `(?=.*[\W])` lookahead cause it to fail since there aren't any non-word characters in those examples?

Comment: Could you please try to match `/^(?=.*[\d])(?=.*([\W])).{8,20}$/i` and tell use what is captured in capturing group `1`? (I'm afraid it's the digit, but you never know)

Comment: Results using Ruby 1.9.3-p327:  r1: - "password"         r2: - "password"
r1: - "1password"        r2: - "1password"
r1: - "password1"        r2: - "password1"
r1: - "pass1word"        r2: - "pass1word"
r1: + "password 1"       r2: + "password 1"
 => ["password", "1password", "password1", "pass1word", "password 1"]    Looks like you may have found a bug with 1.9.2?

Comment: Could you include that in your question please (for the sake of proper formatting)

Comment: @ilanberci, I'm still seeing the same exact results in 1.9.3-p327. https://gist.github.com/a839ed2b3efdc949b894

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This results from the interaction between a couple of regex features and Unicode. `\W` is all non-word characters, which includes [212A - "KELVIN SIGN" `K` (PDF link)](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2100.pdf) and [017F - "LATIN SMALL LETTER LONG S" `ſ` (PDF link)](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0100.pdf). The `/i` adds lower case versions of both of these, which are the “normal” `k` and `s` characters ([006B - "LATIN SMALL LETTER K" and 0073 "LATIN SMALL LETTER S" (PDF link)](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf)).

So it’s the `s` in `password` that’s being interpreted as a non-word character in certain cases.

Note that this only seems to occur when the `\W` is in a character class (i.e. `[\W]`). Also I can only reproduce this in `irb`, inside a standalone script it seems to work as expected.

See [the Ruby bug about this](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4044) for more information.

Comment: Good catch. Not that it matters, but the [actual problem](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4044#note-3) is not `ß` (which is folded to `ss`), but 017F - LATIN SMALL LETTER LONG S `ſ` (which is folded to a single `s`).

Comment: @Pumbaa80 Thanks, that makes more sense, I’ve updated the answer. I took `ß` from [a different comment on the bug report](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4044#note-9). In this case `ß` would also match because of the double-s in `password`, but the actual match is a single s, so it’s probably `ſ`.

Comment: Wow, that's an interesting feature :) Thanks for the explanation and the link to the bug report.

Comment: Since my regex doesn't ultimately need to be case sensitive, simply leaving that flag off results in the expected behavior.